# ViewPager Tab's TextView not getting in center

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The `TextView` inside the `ViewPager's` Tab is not getting in center of the tab.

**ViewPager's Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager_action_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Code to add Tab in ViewPager:**

```
 Tab newTab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this);
    RelativeLayout tabView = (RelativeLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this, R.layout.viewpager_tab_view, null);
    TextView tvTabTitle = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tv_viewpager_tab_title);
    tvTabTitle.setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
    newTab.setCustomView(tabView);
    actionBar.addTab(newTab);
```

**Tab's custom layout:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viewpager_tab_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the screenshot of `ViewPager` Tab only with android's ViewBounds enabled:
[image]

Comment: try this to your `TextView` `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change  **Tab's custom layout:** as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_viewpager_tab_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This link may help you [Tab Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
     android:id="@+id/tv_viewpager_tab_title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="test"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

And replace the code used to add Tab in ViewPager :

```
Tab newTab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this);
    TextView tvTabTitle = (TextView) LinearLayout.inflate(this, R.layout. viewpager_tab_view, null);
    tvTabTitle.setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
    newTab.setCustomView(tabView);
    actionBar.addTab(newTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) plugin to customize your tabs.